# Android Studio - Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync

Tags: android, firebase

When connecting to Firebase via assistant tool in Android Studio, clicking on connect to Firebase, gives me this error:

> Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.

I have already tried to remove dependencies and Google services plugin.

[Error dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNn7r.png)

[Gradle build file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6XNy.png)

[Gradle build file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FigOq.png)

Comment: It looks like there is an error with one of your dependencies, when you hover over that red squiggle error, what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Your build.gradle file should not contain any warnings or errors. and also remove jcenter(). in my case, it worked...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).